# Async Use of Http Get in Node

Tags: node.js, http, asynchronous

For each url in a list of urls, I'm trying to push a string response from that url to an array after requesting it.  This basically maps a list of urls to their contents.  The catch is, the resulting list must be in the same order as the urls.  This is taken from [this challenge](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode/blob/master/exercises/juggling_async/).

I can't figure out why my solution doesn't work.  As far as I can tell, it should put things in the right order.  But it doesn't pass the tests.

```
var http = require('http')
var urls = process.argv.slice(2, process.argv.length)

var result = Array(3)
urls.forEach((url, ind) => {
    var str = ''
    http.get(url, response => {
        response.on('data', d => {
            str+=d.toString()
        })

        response.on('end', () => {
            result[ind] = str

        })
        if (result.every(val => {return val.length!==0})){
            result.forEach(s => {console.log(s)})
        }

    })


})
```

Here are the workshopper's test results:

> 1. ACTUAL:    "She'll be right slaps how he's got a massive jillaroo. As busy as a esky flamin built like a hottie. "
> 2. EXPECTED:  "You little ripper shag on a rock and trent from punchy bottlo. As cunning as a compo no dramas lets get some gyno. Lets get
>      some durry when built like a cranky. "
> 3. ACTUAL:    "You little ripper shag on a rock and trent from punchy bottlo. As cunning as a compo no dramas lets get some gyno. Lets get
>      some durry when built like a cranky. "
> 4. EXPECTED:  "She'll be right slaps how he's got a massive jillaroo. As busy as a esky flamin built like a hottie. "
> 5. ACTUAL:    "She'll be right slaps how he's got a massive jillaroo. As busy as a esky flamin built like a hottie. "
> 6. EXPECTED:  "We're going no dramas heaps trent from punchy christmas. As busy as a ironman mate stands out like a thingo. As dry
>      as a cream to stands out like a rip snorter. Watch out for the ratbag
>      with gutful of cut lunch. Shazza got us some shag on a rock with trent
>      from punchy throw-down. "
> 7. ACTUAL:    ""
> 8. EXPECTED:  ""

Comment: What results are you getting and what were you expecting?

Comment: @devius  I added test results to the question

Comment: I'm not a javascript expert but are you sure the callback you set in http.get is sync ? Cause http.get is definitly meant to be async since it's an http request

Comment: @An-droid  No, it's not sync, that's why I assign the response to the `result` array at the corresponding index of `urls` instead of simply pushing it to `urls`

Comment: *As far as I can tell, it should put things in the right order* - it shouldn't. You can put console.log to *all callback* functions you have and make sure that calling order is not same as you expect. `if (result.every` should be evaluated after all requests have been finished, and there's no such moment in your code. I'd suggest to promisify http and move to promises and possibly async..await, e.g. https://gist.github.com/krnlde/797e5e0a6f12cc9bd563123756fc101f

Comment: @estus  The point of the exercise is to not use special libraries to make it easier.  I don't quite understand your comment.  I know that the callbacks for each url are not called in the same order as the urls.  That's why I specify into which index of the result the response should be placed.  Are you saying that `result[ind]` isn't putting the response in the correct index?

Comment: They are not special libraries. util.promisify and Promise are built-ins. *Are you saying that result[ind] isn't putting the response in the correct index?* - it likely is, but you're unable to check if it's true because `result.every` is in wrong place. Try to put it to `end` callback. Another problem is that `every` doesn't iterate over sparse (unassigned) array elements. It should be `result = Array(3).fill(undefined)` to make it work properly.

Comment: @estus  Thanks, that makes sense.